# ActionBarSherlock (ABS): how to customize the text of action mode close item?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I'm using ABS vers. 4 and I need to simply change the default "Done" text that is displayed besides the action mode close icon, but I really can't figure out how to do it.

I think that text needs to be customizable for at least two good reasons:

- "Done" is not appropriate for all contexts (e.g. "Cancel" could be more appropriate, and I've seen some apps, such as the "My Files" app on Galaxy Tab, use it)
- "Done" needs to be localized according to the user's language

Is it possible to do customize that text? If so can anyone tell me how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I've found a temporary workaround, that I post in the following:

```java
private TextView getActionModeCloseTextView() {
    // ABS 4.0 defines action mode close button text only for "large" layouts
    if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 
        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) 
    {
        // retrieves the LinearLayout containing the action mode close button text
        LinearLayout action_mode_close_button =
            (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.abs__action_mode_close_button);
        // if found, returns its last child 
        // (in ABS 4.0 there is no other way to refer to it, 
        // since it doesn't have an id nor a tag)
        if (action_mode_close_button != null) return (TextView)
            action_mode_close_button.getChildAt(action_mode_close_button.getChildCount() - 1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

That's the method I came up with. Please **NOTE** that it does heavily rely upon the structure of the `abs__action_mode_close_item.xml` of ABS 4.0.

This works for my scenario, but, as you can see, it cannot be considered sufficiently satisfying to promote it to a real "answer", that's why I only edited my previous post.

Hope that helps someone else, but I also hope that someone could share a better and cleaner solution.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a theme to override the default icon:

```
    <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/navigation_back</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/navigation_back</item>
```

Answer (score 7):

I edited the code from PacificSky to be able to customize the color and font size of the close button, both in pre ICS and >ICS.

I created a method named `customizeActionModeCloseButton`

```
private void customizeActionModeCloseButton() {
      int buttonId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_mode_close_button", "id", "android");    
      View v = getGSActivity().findViewById(buttonId);
      if (v == null) {
         buttonId = R.id.abs__action_mode_close_button;
         v = getGSActivity().findViewById(buttonId);
      }
      if (v == null)
         return;
      LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) v;
      if (ll.getChildCount() > 1 && ll.getChildAt(1) != null) {
         TextView tv = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(1);
         tv.setText(R.string.close_action_mode);
         tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
         tv.setTextSize(18);
      }
   }
```

and I call it just after calling `startActionMode()`

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   actionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(this);
   customizeActionModeCloseButton();
   return true;
}
```

Comment: I think we should change "if (v == null)" to "if (v == null || buttonId == 0)" in the fist condition. To avoid there is a view has id = 0. (I faced this problem) ^^

Answer (score 6):

It's been a while, but here's a slightly less hacky solution - putting it out there for posterity.

**For Android versions < ICS**

Put the following line in your application's strings.xml:

```
<string name="abs__action_mode_done">Cancel</string>
```

This overrides the TextView's (defined in ActionBarSherlock/res/layout-large/abs__action_mode_close_item.xml) android:text attribute.

**For Android versions ICS and above**

The native ActionBar functionality is used on ICS and up. You need to find and override the string associated with the done button, using the following code:

```
int buttonId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_mode_close_button", "id", "android");
if (buttonId != 0)
{
    View v = findViewById(buttonId);
    if (v != null)
    {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)v;
        View child = ll.getChildAt(1);
        if (child != null)
        {
            TextView tv = (TextView)child;
            tv.setText(R.string.cancel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to know, but you might want to consider @gonglong's answer. By the way, I find ridiculous to have to do this to fix an Android's API usability fault.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for PacificSky's answer. It's useful for my case.

Something needs to be explained here is that `findViewById(buttonId)` might return `null` in some cases such as called in o`nCreateActionMode()` function, because the `LinearLayout` for ActionMode close button not yet initialized at that time I guess.

I want to hide the action mode close button, so i just `sendEmptyMessageDelayed` in `onCreateActionMode()`  and call PacificSky's 200ms later. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach with Java code:

```
private void customizeActionModeCloseButton(String title, int iconID) {
          int buttonId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_mode_close_button", "id", "android");    
          View v = findViewById(buttonId);
          if (v == null) {
             buttonId = R.id.abs__action_mode_close_button;
             v = findViewById(buttonId);
          }
          if (v == null)
             return;
          LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) v;
          if (ll.getChildCount() > 1 && ll.getChildAt(1) != null) {
             //custom icon
             ImageView img = (ImageView) ll.getChildAt(0);
             img.setImageResource(iconID);
             //custom text
             TextView tv = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(1);
             tv.setText(title);
             tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
          }
       }
```

Answer (score -1):

com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode contains method:

```
setTitle
```

It is used to change text near Close Icon in the ActionBar.
ActionMode is available in your com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode.Callback interface implementation methods, like onCreateActionMode.

What you can do - is save incoming ActionMode reference and use it later to change title as your like. Or, if it is not dynamic - you can setup at with your constant in onCreateActionMode.

Comment: The setTitle is used to set the "main" title of the ActionMode, not the text that is displayed next to the "done" button in the left corner when a large layout is rendered.